# Find the $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ of the areas

Tags: calculus, geometry, limits, contest-math

Let $ABC$ be an equilateral triangle of area 1. Let $D_1 $ also be any point on the side $AB$. Set points $D_n, E_n$ and $F_n$ as follows: $E_n$ is the perpendicular foot by $D_n $ to $BC, F_n $ is the perpendicular foot by $E_n$ and $AC$ and $D_ {n + 1}$ is the perpendicular foot by $F_n $ to $AB.$ Find $ \lim_{n\to\infty}Area (D_nE_nF_n)$

I was thinking of basically comparing the area under the curve with a sum, but I don't know if it can help exactly.

Comment: A hint: Have you tried sketching this process? In particular, I think it would help you to identify the (unique) fixed point of this process, and see what happens when you iterate the process starting from an arbitrary $D_n$. You'll find that you don't actually need to compute the area of each triangle to work out what the limit must be, although making the area argument formal might be a bit fiddly.

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: @EsposaDoYoongi Brazil Omerj olympiad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will find an expression for $[D_nE_nF_n]$ in terms of $AD_n$. Let $AD_n=s$ for brevity, and scale up so that the $AB=1$. We find that $\angle D_nE_nB=90^{\circ}$ and $\angle F_nE_nC=30^{\circ}$, so $\angle D_nE_nF_n=60^{\circ}$. From some quick length chasing, $E_nD_n=\frac{\sqrt{3}(1-s)}{2}$ and $E_nF_n=\frac{\sqrt{3}(1+s)}{4}$. Thus,$$[D_nE_nF_n]=\frac{1}{2}*\sin{60^{\circ}}*E_nD_n*E_nF_n=\frac{3\sqrt{3}(1-s^2)}{32}$$Now we will find the value of $s$ as $n\to \infty$. Again, from a quick length chase we get that if $AD_n=s$ then$$AD_{n+1}=\frac{3-s}{8}\implies AD_n+8AD_{n+1}=3$$Solving the recursion gives$$AD_n=\left(\frac{-1}{8}\right)^{n-1}\left(AD_1-\frac{1}{3}\right)+\frac{1}{3}$$Taking the limit gives$$\lim_{n\to \infty} AD_n=\frac{1}{3}$$Thus, we get our area to approach $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{36}$. Scaling back up, our answer is $\frac{1}{9}$.